# Magento 2 MSI - How to listen the event of all source item stock update API

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, inventory, cataloginventory, multi-source-inventory

Am using the below rest API to update bulk product's Stock information

```
/rest/all/V1/inventory/source-items
```

My requirement is that I need to listen the observer or some file whenever this API is triggered to write my custom logic.

Can anyone help me on how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an after plugin to `\Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface::execute` API